# React Native Android gives error when adding package

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

So I downgrade the version of my React Native to version 57.3 because there are so many bugs in the latest version. At first, the React Native Project wokrs well without adding any package like React Native Maps but when I add it the run it fresh it gives me an error. The setup of my React Native Project is correct.

I tried it to run as Administrator and not as Administrator.

[image]
Environment:

`"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },`

Comment: make sure that you did `react-native link react-native-maps`

Comment: Do I have to? Because I added it manually.

Comment: not needed if you did it manually

Comment: adb is installed? were you able to run on android before without maps?

Comment: There's an error again. It says "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue."

Comment: After I did `react-native link react-native-maps` it works. But I tried to rebuild it again the 1st error which is the error of without Admin appears again.

Comment: did you notice `insufficient memory`?

Comment: Yea. But I tried to do the `react-native link react-native-maps` it works again. But I think in the next build I will get errors again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be an issue with heap size. Please try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to your `Manifest.xml` and rebuild your project with below command:

```
react-native run-android
```

Your manifest.xml will be like this:

```
android:name=".MainApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:largeHeap="true"
```